# At what age do children usually learn to write letters of the alphabet?

Tags: pre-schooler, education, milestones

My son is 3.5 years old and attends kindergarten. He is one of the youngest in his class. He has not been showing any interest in writing letters of the alphabet and quickly loses focus. His teacher has told us to make him practice writing letters at home. I am wondering if he is too young to learn writing. At what age do children usually start writing letters?

Comment: Check out the Leapfrog Letter Factory videos too.

Comment: did you check his little motor skills. Maybe he finds hard to hold a pencil. And he needs some practice on small muscles on the hand?

Comment: @BaharAykaç This was 3 years back. All is good now. He can read and write very well 

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here, in Germany, kids begin to learn to write letters in the first form of elementary school, which children can enter no earlier than at age 6, and quite a few kids start school when they are 7. There really is no concerted effort to teach children to write earlier than that. Nevertheless German adults can read and write as well as adults from other countries. I therefore think that you can relax and allow your child to be a child for a few years more.

Comment: This is a good approach, but it doesn't answer the question. The question isn't "When do schools start to teach the alphabet?" But I'm sure the OP takes comfort in your answer.

Comment: @anongoodnurse The question is: "At what age do children usually learn to write alphabets?" My answer is: "In my country, children usually learn to write alphabets when they are six years old." It seems to me that my answer answers the question rather exactly.

Comment: Same for the Netherlands (well they don't start at 7). Between 4 and 6 they may be introduced to letters but it's more of a play thing, writing really starts in "group 3", more or less 6+.

Comment: @user31704: While that *may* be true, it doesn't follow logically. The fact that it's one of the first things that is taught in schools only tells us that it's a skillset that is imperative to schooling, and that age 6-7 is the *upper bound* after which we expect close to all children to have acquired this skill. If 75% (made up figure) of kids knew how to write letters on admission, this would still be the first thing schools taught, because everyone needs to be on board with it.

Comment: @DavidHedlund: yes, but that sounds very far fetched to me.

Comment: @Remco: Granted, this question shoots off in many directions. OP is asking both if their child is *too young* (lower bound), and when they *usually start* (mean). This answer seems to provide when children are *at the very latest expected to start* (upper bound). But on a personal note, I think "His teacher has told us to make him practice X" is too harsh for a 3.5 year old almost regardless of the X. There's still great individual variability at this age, so while I think anon's objection is legitimate, I wholeheartedly agree with the spirit of the conclusions of this answer.

Answer (score 8):

According to the US Department of Education, your son is of the age when children typically become interested in writing (or pretending to write) the letters of their language. The American Academy of Pediatrics doesn't mention the child's interest in learning letters until the age of four. So you can see there is room for individuality.

---

It has been shown in study after study that the single most important activity in language acquisition, improvement, and a desire to read is to yourself read to your child every day. I have not seen a study that emphasizes the *need to be able to write letters by 3.5*, however, studies of letter-writing skills and their implications often begin in preschool with 3 - 5 year olds.

The importance of learning the alphabet at 3.5 years on long-term goals (e.g. the ability to read/spell) is not clear, but clearly your preschool teacher has an agenda for your child, and it is an achievement goal (i.e. set by educators, probably at the state level.) Forcing him to practice his letters may make him more resistant, not less, unless it's incorporated into an activity he really likes. It also matters if he is capable at the level of fine motor skills to form letters. It's important to understand why your child has no "interest". Is it because they are frustrated or have a fear of failure? These and other possibilities need to be addressed with your child and his teacher.

At 3.5, most kids will find it difficult to write letters neatly or in a small size. They can 'write big', though, especially if it's interesting.

Whether you help at home depends on how important you think cooperating with your child's teacher is. You might ask the teacher the reasoning behind the goal, and how you can help.

If you want to encourage your child to learn his letters, I would suggest reading about the ways you can do this. Some ways including pointing out letters (and their sound) while you read, i.e. "read with your finger" by underlining the words with your finger as you go along  (something children themselves used to be admonished for doing!) At an opportune time, you can go back to the story with your child

> Remember we read about the Cat in the Hat last night? The word *cat* is spelled (show) C-A-T. Let's try to write these letters with your finger/(other).

Make it large and make it fun. Writing in the sand is fun (you can make a small shallow sandbox for this). Writing on a whiteboard with a large marker or in thick chalk on the sidewalk is easier than on paper with a crayon. Make a game of it. (On the sidewalk, you can make it about them, e.g.)

> What do you want to say? Ok, then we need the letter *I* and then a space, then *A* and *M*, another space, and finally, a *B*, *A*, *T*, *M*, *A*, *N* (with you helping, of course.)

Or, ask your child to name a letter, when he does, write the letter, and draw something amusing that begins with that letter (e.g. an egg with legs.)

Please note that letter recognition and letter-sound recognition are different things, so the second activity is both a letter-recognition and a letter-sound recognition exercise.*

*<sub>Other ways to teach letter-sound recognition is verbally. Questions like, "What sound do you hear in *bat* but not in *at*? That's right, /b/. The letter that has the /b/ sound is *B*. (Or "cake" but not "ache" /"pants"/"ants", "cup"/"up", etc.)? Start with letters at the beginning of the word, then letters at the end (fork/for, team/tea, farm/far, etc.) Also, some letters are easier than others.</sub>

<sub>[Typical Language Accomplishments for Children, Birth to Age 6 -- Helping Your Child Become a Reader](https://www2.ed.gov/parents/academic/help/reader/part9.html)</sub>
[Your Three Year Old](http://www.pbs.org/parents/childdevelopmenttracker/three/index.html)

Comment: For kids like mine with sensory sensitivities, writing in a medium like sand or paint is *extremely* offputting for him. Make sure you're doing it in a medium they love. (for mine, that's chalk or touchscreens.)

Comment: @JonathanHartley - Touchscreens are a great idea, thanks for adding that. Most kids love to play in sand, though some kids definitely hate the stuff. I've seen recommendations to trace letters on *sandpaper*. Ugh. Common sense must prevail.

Answer (score 2):

It's different in different countries. Which country are you referring to, or do you want a general answer?

I live outside the U.S, so where I am children are encouraged to learn alphabet recognition at about age 4, and it continues through to 5&6 yo. Usually they start learning to recognise the alphabet at about age 4-5 and practice "writing" their name using alphabet magnets or stickers. Nothing super formal though, so not all of the 4-5 yo will be expected to pass a test and write out every alphabet letter an adult calls out.

Answer (score 0):

A pre-school or nursery class, Where our child learn new things and interact with their age level childs, dealing with cooperative behaviour, manage the instructions given by their teacher.

Here writing means, child is able to write or draw what letter or object we want to write them, hold the pencil in correct way and child showing some interest in the writing art.

When child is able to handle writing art, like writing alphabets or numbers or draw some objects(circle, square), coloring in them etc. That means in upcoming years(Kinder Garden) classes child will be able to write. They will be understand or familiar with these activities.

So as per my opinion When child cross the age of 3.5 years, he/she is should be able to write or draw or dealing with basic written base.
Again here writing means,  write or draw letter(alphabet) or object(draw) as per instruct.